# Write literal braces followed by variable in heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

```
        $js = <<<EOS
        var data = {$jsObjectData};
EOS;
```

results in `var data = ~some object data~`

Escaping the brace:

```
        $js = <<<EOS
        var data = \{$jsObjectData};
EOS;
```

results in `var data = \{~some object data~}`

I can't understand why does that backslash leak through it.

Desired output: `var data = {~some object data~}`

Comment: Why not use [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) instead?

Comment: @BLaZuRE I still want that $jsObjectData to be evaluated, but without consuming that braces arround it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wrap it inside an extra pair of curly braces.

```
$js = <<<EOS
        var data = {{$jsObjectData}};
EOS;
```